# To what extent can constraint forces emulate "real" forces?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Consider a charged particle under the influence of a perpendicular magnetic field. This system can be emulated exactly with that of a bead on a hoop (with no external forces), with the action of the external force (due to the field) taken over by the constraint force given by $x^2+y^2=R^2$.

However, in general, knowing (and parametrizing) the trajectory of a particle and subsequently using Lagrange's multipliers to find its dynamics is not enough to emulate the "real" system. (For example, the trajectory of a particle dropped under the influence of gravity is a straight line; but constraining a particle to move in a straight line and keeping no external forces will not give us back this system, in general.)

Under what conditions, then, can a set of forces $ \{F_i\} $ be described by a set of constraint equations $ \{g_i\} $ (where, to my understanding, $g_i$ will be a multivariable polynomial in $(x, y, z)$)?

Comment: To clarify:  by "described by a set of constraint equations $\{ g_i \}$", do you mean that "the particle's motion is the same as in an equivalent system in which constraint forces are the only forces acting on the particle"?

Comment: (If so, it seems to me that $\vec{F} \perp \vec{v}$ is definitely necessary and probably sufficient, but I haven't gone through the argument carefully.)

Comment: the bead on the hoop can rotate with any speed, in the magnetic field the charge radius depends on the velocity. so its not the same. On the other hand, the force of the loop is  a centripetal force real and you can calculate it depending on the speed .